# Не видно мою переменную

Tags: php, mysql

начал изучать PHP и MySQL. Пишу форму для авторизации. Не понимаю, почему при подключении файла, в котором инициализирую переменную через mysqli_connect(), данную переменную не видно.

файл, в котором я инициализировал переменную:

```
    <?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mytest');

    if (!$connect){

        die('Can`t connect to Database');

    }
    ?>
```

Файл, в котором я пытаюсь вызвать переменную:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'connect.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $pass_confirm = $_POST['pass_confirm'];

    if($password === $pass_confirm){

        $password = md5($password);

        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `password`) VALUES ('', '', '')"); //PHPSTORM ЖАЛУЕТСЯ НА $connect, "переменная не объявлена"


        header('Location: ../greetings_page.php');
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Passwords are different';
        header('Location: ../register_page.php');


    }
    ?>
```

Оба файла находятся в одной директории. PHPStorm жалуется на

Comment: жалуется на....?))) это недописано или жаргонно выражено? :D

Comment: не знаю точно должен ли видеть в таком случае шторм переменную.....сам код-то работает? пробелма в иотге в чём? всего лишь в том, что шторму что-то не нравится?

Comment: прошу прощения, что ответил спустя длительное время
PHPSTORM ЖАЛУЕТСЯ НА $connect, "переменная не объявлена"
Сам код не работает так, как задумано. Т.е., у меня есть база данных, в которую должны записываться значения, которые я ввожу со страницы, но при вводе в базе ничего не появляется. Прикол в том, что я все делал по гайду с ютуба, однако, сколько бы я не сверял с кодом автора, у меня все равно выдает ошибку....

Comment: На данный момент предлагаю вам включить отображение ошибок и воспользоваться отладой (можно посмотреть тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482  как это делается).... возможно ...а) шторм ругается но ошибка в другом........ б) возможно ошибка всё же в пути и отображение ошибок поможет увидеть что конкретно не так

Comment: большое спасибо,попробую)